# how to get all the events from a user with facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I asked access to user_events and friends_events. And this is the url that i get the json stuff from.

```
https://graphs.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I kept getting {"data":[]}

I checked out my facebook page and i have like a million events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using https://graphs.facebook.com/me/events only gets events that you participate or are unsure.

But. You can use FQL to get all events from a user. Participanting or Not.

```
select eid, uid, rsvp_status from event_member where uid = me()
```

rsvp_status can be

> "attending","declined","not_replied" and "unsure"

check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20eid,%20uid,%20rsvp_status%20from%20event_member%20where%20uid%20=%20me%28%29)

Comment: fql is deprecated it seems. Is there a way to get all events using graph api ?

Comment: Sorry, there is a long time that I don't work with the fb api. If you found how to do it with graph, tell us.